# Add single contact from phonebook at a time

Tags: android

This is my main activity code in which I am able to add a single contact to an `ArrayList`:

```
public class EmergencyContact extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private ArrayList<ContactPojo> contactPojolist = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView emerg_recycler;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emergency_contact);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        emerg_recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.emerg_contact_recycler);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        emerg_recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uri);
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri uri = intent.getData();

                String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int numberColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                String number = cursor.getString(numberColumnIndex);

                int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);

                ContactPojo contactPojo = new ContactPojo();
                contactPojo.setName(name);
                contactPojo.setNumber(number);
                contactPojolist.add(contactPojo);
                RentalAdapter  emergencyContact = new RentalAdapter(EmergencyContact.this, contactPojolist);
                emerg_recycler.setAdapter(emergencyContact);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

But When I am trying to add another contact, my activity refreshes and loses its previous data. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: try to print size of arraylist like contactPojolist.size();

check if count will be increse then you need to notify adapter as @Thambidurai said

Answer (score 0):

Try to do notifydatasetchanged for the adapter
. . . . . emergencyContact. notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: no, my  contactPojolist.size(); is remain same when i add another contact. The problem is when i m try to add new contact my activity is refresh. and contactPojolist also refresh.

Comment: My issue is solved, this happen because of my mobile issue it calls onCreate every time and refresh my activity